# ERROR 1054 MySql for my Query

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I run the following query in MySql

```
SELECT count(*) 
  FROM `pitches` AS `Pitch` 
        INNER JOIN `business_sectors_pitches` AS `BusinessSector` 
           ON (`BusinessSector`.`pitch_id` = `Pitch`.`id`) 
         LEFT JOIN `investments` AS `Investment` 
           ON (`Investment`.`pitch_id` = `Pitch`.`id`) 
         LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User` 
           ON (`Pitch`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
         LEFT JOIN `loan_pitches` AS `LoanPitch` 
           ON (`LoanPitch`.`pitch_id` = `Pitch`.`id`) 
         LEFT JOIN `equity_pitches` AS `EquityPitch` 
           ON (`EquityPitch`.`pitch_id` = `Pitch`.`id`) 
 WHERE `Pitch`.`status` = 1 
   AND `Pitch`.`required_funding` >= 0 
   AND `Pitch`.`required_funding` <= 1500000 
 GROUP BY `Pitch`.`id` 
having ( (     sum(`Investment`.`amount`) / `Pitch`.`required_funding` >= 0 
           and sum(`Investment`.`amount`) / `Pitch`.`required_funding` <= 1
         )  or sum(`Investment`.`amount`) / `Pitch`.`required_funding` is null 
       )
       and count(`Investment`.`id`) >= 0 
       and count(`Investment`.`id`) <= 200 ;
```

and get the following Error

> ```
> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Pitch.required_funding' in 'having clause'
> ```

I found that the having need to be replaced by where, but I couldn't make it works.

This code is generated from my Cakephp code, but I can't make it works in mysql client.

Second try according to @GolezTrol comment

```
SELECT count(*)    
FROM `pitches` AS `Pitch`          
INNER JOIN `business_sectors_pitches` AS `BusinessSector`             
  ON (`BusinessSector`.`pitch_id` = `Pitch`.`id`)           
LEFT JOIN `investments` AS `Investment`             
  ON (`Investment`.`pitch_id` = `Pitch`.`id`)           
LEFT JOIN `users` AS `User`             
  ON (`Pitch`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`)           
LEFT JOIN `loan_pitches` AS `LoanPitch`             
  ON (`LoanPitch`.`pitch_id` = `Pitch`.`id`)           
LEFT JOIN `equity_pitches` AS `EquityPitch`             
  ON (`EquityPitch`.`pitch_id` = `Pitch`.`id`)   
WHERE `Pitch`.`status` = 1     
  AND `Pitch`.`required_funding` >= 0     
  AND `Pitch`.`required_funding` <= 1500000 
  AND ( ((select sum(amount) from investments group by pitch_id)  / `Pitch`.`required_funding` >= 0             
  AND (select sum(amount)  from investments group by pitch_id) / `Pitch`.`required_funding` <= 1)  
  OR (select sum(amount)  from investments group by pitch_id) / `Pitch`.`required_funding` is null);
```

Comment: Side note: You risk division by zero, since you divide by `Pitch.required_funding` and that field is `>=` to zero according to the `where` conditions.

Comment: Side note: You are allowed to have breaks in SQL statements. A line of 400 characters isn't really readable.

Comment: Note: You are grouping by pitch.id (and pitch.id alone), but you don't select pitch.id. If this query would work, then you would have a bunch of counts without a possibility to know to which pitches they belong.

Comment: I think you can solve your problem by adding `Pitch.required_funding` to the `group by` clause, but I'm not sure if that does what you want, regarding my comments above.

Comment: actually what I'm after is to count number of rows if we had **SELECT * ** your last comment to add the `Pitch.required_funding` the code wouldn't break, but it doesn't bring the result I want.

Comment: In that case, you should remove the group by clause completely, make a subselect to query the sum of `investment.amount` per pitch, and do the division in the `where` clause. If you do that, the count will give you the number of pitches to which the defines conditions apply. If you need the number of investments as well, return their count in the subselect I mentioned, and sum that sum again in the main query.

Comment: I removed the last 2 lines of the query. I think I did what you suggested and get an error subquery returns more than 1 row. I'll edit my question as it's too long here.